# pg_dump dumps data from dblinks?

Tags: postgresql, backup

I'm working with a postgres database recovered from a dump, and there are some empty tables and foreign keys with null values. I'm suspecting the dump could be incomplete, because original database had these data from dblinks.

I couldn't find it in the documentation. When we do the `pg_dump` it dumps the data from dblinks?

Comment: Do you mean views referencing `dblink` in the `from` clause?

Comment: @Colin'tHart Yes.

Comment: A foreign key can never point to a view, nor could the contents of a table depend on a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, pg_dump won't dump data from views. Views don't store data: they're purely a definition of how to retrieve the data -- a stored select statment, if you will.